# Stuck threads in weblogic due to xmlbeans

Tags: apache-poi, weblogic, xmlbeans

We see multiple stuck threads in weblogic while using apache poi to write data to excel.

```
 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" Id=2734 RUNNABLE

                at javax.xml.namespace.QName.equals(QName.java:369)

                at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.count(Locale.java:2062)

                at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.count_elements(Xobj.java:2068)

                at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTMergeCellsImpl.sizeOfMergeCellArray(Unknown Source)

                -  locked org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale@4e4edf28

                at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getNumMergedRegions(XSSFSheet.java:816)
```

Looks like the issue is with xmlbeans. Restarting weblogic server temporarily fixes the issue. Looking for some help in debugging.

Comment: What version of Apache XMLBeans are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Only one thread dump is not enough. Take several TD to see if the code is always stuck in the same method.

Comment: We have taken several thread dumps in production and the code is always stuck in the same method. I have commented the method in non prod environment. This time its stuck in a different method related to poi but the error and stacktrace is the same. Its related to xmlbeans